# ColdFusion dev in Eclipse vs Intellij

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, intellij-idea

Getting thrown into ColdFusion dev at work and just starting out, I wonder if there are any advantages (or disadvantages) of using Eclipse vs Intellij. I'm used to working in Intellij on Groovy/Grails and have close to zero hands-on time with Eclipse. The shop I'm in mostly uses Eclipse (I think because it's free and not much else), some use Dreamweaver (1 person me thinks).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have used Dreamweaver for CF, also Homesite (old school CF editor). I have also used CF plugin for Eclipse, but at first, when new to Eclipse, found it too heavy. If there is a plugin for CF in Intellij, I would go that rout.  Good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a CF Developer that has been playing with intelliJ of late!  I must say I do love the smoothness of intelliJ.  IntelliJ does has have a CF code library ( http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=3571 ).

I don't use Eclipse for CF Development, but do use CFBuilder, which is based on Eclipse.

I personally prefer intelliJ as an IDE, but prefer CF Builder when working with CF.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options for working with Eclipse for ColdFusion Development:

- [cfeclipse](http://cfeclipse.org/) - an open source, free plugin for Eclipse
- [cfBuilder](http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion-builder/features.html) - the 'official' IDE, sold and distributed by Adobe.

There is also a [plugin for IntelliJ](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cfml-plugin-for-intellij-idea) which I have no personal experience using however I note that some highly respected CF devs are using it and preferring it to the Eclipse-based options.

My team and I currently use CFBuilder 2 and find that to be good enough for our needs. The biggest criticism I see about CFBuilder/Eclipse is that it can perform poorly on older PCs and the common solution is to increase the RAM available to it.

The benefit my team finds with CFBuilder is that the full Eclipse plug-in ecosystem is available giving us bundled options for source control and other development tools. (The same may exist for IntelliJ but I have no personal experience with it.)

Dreamweaver, especially a recent version, is an option and many CF devs swear by ColdFusion Studio which is a very old program and might be hard to get your hands on. Finally, there is also a [plugin for Notepad++](http://ricardo.parente.us/2011/01/coldfusion-plugin-for-notepad/) for the times where you need to make a quick edit to a file and don't require a full IDE.

Comment: "The biggest criticism I see about CFBuilder/Eclipse is that it can perform poorly on older PCs" -- Right, except missing Linux edition.

Comment: ah yes, certainly true - i'm a windows guy so that doesn't bother me too much but it certainly is a common issue.

Answer (score 2):

The editor that a lot of people have been using for ColdFusion lately is SublimeText 2 (http://www.sublimetext.com/2) with the official ColdFusion Package (https://github.com/SublimeText/ColdFusion).  The link I posted below from Nettuts will help you get up and running with the PackageControl package that makes installing the ColdFusion package very easy.

Sublime is lightweight, powerful, and a pleasure to code in.  It has small animations that make it feel responsive, and the birds eye map view of the code can be very useful.  It even has some code insite that I find really helpful.

Heres a great post on Nettuts to get you started: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/sublime-text-2-tips-and-tricks/